# Django AuthenticationForm is not working this give error name 'UsernameField' is not defined

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

This is my code

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = UsernameField(label='username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True,'class':'form-control'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label =_("Password"), strip=False, widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete':'current-password', 'class':'form-control'}))
```

when I run the server then this error occur (NameError: name 'UsernameField' is not defined)

```
    class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
  File "E:\07_Django_All\03_ecommerce_site(Project)\Ecommerce_site\app\forms.py", line 19, in LoginForm
    username = UsernameField(label='username', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'autofocus':True,'class':'form-control'}))
NameError: name 'UsernameField' is not defined
```

Comment: what us UsernameField you should just put models.CharField i think

Comment: If you copied the `UsernameField` from original Django code, so you should also import it.

Comment: It is defined in `AbstractUser` refer [GitHub](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L377) and this is also used in `username` field of `AuthenticationForm`.

Answer (score 0):

You must import the `UsernameField` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to import the `UsernameField` from `django.contrib.auth.forms`

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UsernameField
```

2. You have to import the `gettext` and `gettext_lazy as _` from `django.utils.translation`

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext,gettext_lazy as _
```